# Not able to use foreign key from another app?

Tags: python, django

**travelers.models**

```
from django.db import models

    class ShortInfoTraveler(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

**blogs.models**

```
from django.db import models
from travelers.models import ShortInfoTraveler

class Title(models.Model):
    shortinfotraveler = models.ForeignKey('ShortInfoTraveler')
    title_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

And When I run makemigrations, Terminal show following-

```
ERRORS: blogs.Title.shortinfotraveler: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with 
model 'blogs.ShortInfoTraveler', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting your foreign key like this:

```
models.ForeignKey('travelers.ShortInfoTraveler')
```

If you want to use a string to set the foreign key relation.

Or you should just set `ShortInfoTraveler` without it being a string since you've imported it.

Setting it to `"ShortInfoTraveler"` is looking for the model in the current models file instead of your other app which you can see in the error message output back.